# Integrating Blazor Client side into an ASP.Net MVC Core 3.1 app. Is it logical or am I better off building new Blazor app from scratch?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am in the middle of a project building an internal admin web site using Asp.Net MVC Core 3.1 
Some of the features I need in the app could benefit from Blazor Client side. (Single Page App features?)
My question is would it be logical to try to somehow bring Blazor Client into the existing project or would it make sense to start from scratch using the supplied templates to create a Blazor app and discard my MVC app?
From reading various posts, most which are pre core 3.1, it's hard to get an understanding of the viability of going this route.

Comment: It kind of depends on how far into your MVC app you are, how much of a purist you want to be, whether the Blazor portions can be componentized...  I'm sure I've left a few other considerations out.

Comment: I attended a Blazor event recently, and it seemed to me like its not really ready for prime time yet. still need some JS, still need to fall back to server side for some browsers